# Does Vaishnavite scripture extol the superiority of Garuda over the vahanas of other Gods?

Tags: garuda

Vishnu is considered superior to all, Lakshmi is considered superior to the spouses of other Gods - how about their mounts?

Is there scripture putting Garuda over Nandi et al?

Comment: Garuda is nitya suri, so he is treated as superior to Shiva, leave alone Nandi.

Comment: Do we know transitivity holds if A >B and B>C then A > C?  @Lazy Lubber  At any rate when Siva is about to kill Garuda Vishnu had to intervene in Devon Ke Dev Mahadev

Comment: Anyway thats just the Iyengar version - I doubt that Garuda has any importance for Gaudiyas, Ramanandis et al  @Lazy Lubber